# Javadoc for a New java maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc

I created a new Maven project and generated Javadocs through eclipse. It created a lot of html files in the project directory inside a folder called "doc". 
Now I want to distribute this project as a dependency to my colleague and he does not have the source of the project I created. He is only adding my project as a dependency. He says he cannot see the javadoc when he hovers on a method that I created in my project.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/index.html) to the project (plugins section of your pom.xml), instead of generating the Javadocs through Eclipse. Please have a look at the [jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html) goal. If done correctly, the Maven build will package a javadoc jar beside the normal jar file. The build will result in following jars:

1. ${artifactId}-${version}.jar
2. ${artifactId}-${version}-javadoc.jar

If you want to provide the sources additionally, the [maven-source-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) (goal jar) will do the job for you.

The installation of the jar file, the javadoc file and in case the source file into your colleague's local Maven repository can be done with the [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/).